# toggle boolean value equivalent for strings

Tags: javascript, string, toggle

I know you can do the following in javascript to toggle a boolean in a one liner.

```
var toggle = false;
if(true) toggle != toggle;
```

but is this also possible with a string? i know it can be done by some if statements. But is it possible to do it in a oneliner? something like this:

```
var string_toggle = "CAT";
if(true) "CAT" = "ESP" || "ESP" = "CAT";
```

If it is not clear what i am asking let me know so i can improve the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).

```
string_toggle = (string_toggle === "CAT") ? "ESP" : "CAT";
```

This effectively translates to:

```
if (string_toggle === "CAT") {
  string_toggle = "ESP";
} else {
  string_toggle = "CAT";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are a heavy user,why not to make some class?`overkill`

Here im using [this](http://es6-features.org/#ClassDefinition) javascript syntax.

You should check ECMAScript 6,you will like it!

```js
class ToggleValue {

  constructor(value1,value2){
    
    this.values = [value1,value2]
    this.pointer = 0
  
  }
  
  toggle(){
    
     this.pointer = +!this.pointer
    
  }
  
  valueOf(){
  
    return this.values[this.pointer]
  
  }
  
}



var dupaOrGrabowa = new ToggleValue('dupa', 'grabowa')

dupaOrGrabowa.toggle()
console.log(dupaOrGrabowa + '')
dupaOrGrabowa.toggle()
console.log(dupaOrGrabowa + '')
```

Comment: This is total overkill and I love it.